# Como usar o arquivo Strings dentro do codigo

Tags: java, android

Olá,dentro do XML do MainActivity no Android Studio eu consigo usar o @string/STRING eu gostaria de saber como eu referenciaria uma string que eu tenho dentro do strings.xml na pasta res do Android Studio.

Exemplo strings.xml

```
<string name="beer">Beer</string>
```

Exemplo strings(pt-br)

```
<string name="beer">Cerveja</string>
```

No código eu queria referenciar isso:

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast;
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.ce : toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), QUERIA_REFERENCIAR_AQUI ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show(); break;
                    [...]
                    default : break;
                }
```

Para que assim haja tradução no meu app até nessas mensagens, pois no layout, funciona de boa. Obrigado!

Seria possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para referenciar através do java utilize a seguinte chama:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast;
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.ce : toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.beer),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show(); break;
                    [...]
                    default : break;
            }
```

Uma outra forma também muito fácil é você escrever o texto e, após, clica com o botão direito do mouse cima do texto e procura a opção (acredito que a primeira opção) para add automaticamente ao arquivo de String xml e você informa somente o nome (key), que no caso será beer.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado!